# Is a JSON library allowed to quote slashes?

Tags: json, quoting

I noticed that depending on the implementation, some JSON libraries quote `/` characters, others don't.

Example 1: Lua

```
local cjson = require 'cjson'
print(cjson.encode({ x = "/" }))
--> {"x":"\/"}
```

Example 2: JavaScript

```
console.log(JSON.stringify({ x: "/" }))
--> '{"x":"/"}'
```

I wonder if the quoting of Lua's cjson libray is a bug or a valid feature. If it is not, I'm concerned about base64 encoded strings that are sent over the network and should be processed by any language. I'm concerned about possibly unintended side-effects of Lua cjson when it changes strings after first decoding the JSON string and than encoding it again, for example:

```
local x = '{"x":"/"}'
print(x)
--> {"x":"/"}
print(cjson.encode(cjson.decode(x)))
--> {"x":"\/"}
```

I wonder if this is allowed. Is it still the same JSON data? I would have expected that the actual string contents should not be changed by applying a decode followed by an encode operation.

**Is it allowed in JSON to quote a `'/'`, or does it change the payload in a non standard conformant way?**

From what I tested, assuming that `"/" == "\/"` holds is not portable over different languages. In a small sample of languages, I found mixed results. Some accept it, some don't, some accept it but issue warnings (so it is maybe not portable). Here is an overview:

```
+------------+-------------+----------------------------------+
|  Language  | "/" == "\/" |              Notes               |
+------------+-------------+----------------------------------+
| Lua        | true        | -                                |
| JavaScript | true        | -                                |
| C++        | true        | warning: unknown escape sequence |
| Python     | false       | -                                |
| Ruby       | true        | -                                |
+------------+-------------+----------------------------------+
```

Comment: Regarding your test approach, note that `"/" == "\/"` is testing the language string literal format and the string comparison behaviour. JSON encoded data, on the other hand, must be read by a JSON parser, which may (and does) parse strings in specific JSON format. The answers below explain why both `\/` and `/` are valid.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[The spec](http://json.org/) defines a string as

[image: JSON string formal definition]

So the sequence `\/` is clearly allowed. But it is not necessary, since `/` also falls into the *"Any Unicode character except `"` or `\` or control character"* range.

The "warning: unknown escape sequence" is not correct in this case.

---

> If it is not, I'm concerned about base64 encoded strings that are sent over the network and should be processed by any language.

I'm not sure I understand. Base64 and JSON have nothing to do with each other.

Comment: The JSON data contains strings that represent Base64 encoded data. If these strings are changed, I'm concerned that the receiver will not get the same result when it decodes them. Agreed, that Base64 has nothing to do with JSON, but it was just an example where I'm not comfortable about changes made by the JSON library to the strings.

Comment: I thought something like that, but a string in JSON is a JSON string, no matter if it faintly resembles Base64. After decoding, it could be anything, from plain text to HTML to Base64. A non-broken JSON parser will do the right thing when it encounters `\/` and given the way parsers work in general (and how the spec looks like) there is little reason to assume that this should pose any more of a problem than `\\ ` or `\u002f` would.

Comment: Thanks, that is a good point. I also come to the conclusion that sending data this way is safe.

Answer (score 2):

Going by [the ECMA-404 spec](http://www.ecma-international.org/publications/files/ECMA-ST/ECMA-404.pdf), it *should* be allowed:

> \/ represents the solidus character (U+002F).
>
> The following four cases all produce the same result:
>
> - "\u002F"
> - "\u002f"
> - "\/"
> - "/"